# DB cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 612

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

I'm trying to do some excercises from exam 70-515. Unfortunately I fail while trying to attach Northwind to a grid-control. It would result in:
`NORTHWND.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 612 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.`

I use Windows 7 Home and MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. As fas as I understand this error, SQL Express must be an old version on my system. I downloaded and installed SQL Express 2008r2 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/). No effect. From other sources I figured out that I might need to change the instance name: Tools -> Options -> Database Tools -> Data Connections -> SQL Server Instance Name. There it is written SQLEXPRESS. I don't know what else I should insert there?

Comment: From a quick google it would seem that you are connecting to a 2005 instance not a 2008 instance I think?

Comment: Yes - but how can I tell Visual Studio to connect with the 2008 instance which I installed?

Comment: I try this one. still got the same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that deinstalling SQL Express and reinstall the latest version fixed the problem. I chose SQLSERVER2008 as Instance-Name while installing and set it in Visual Studio as described above.

Comment: I try this one. still got the same error. Please help to solve

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Services control panel and look for a service named `SQL Server (XXX)` -- that `XXX` is the name of the instance that service is running. You just have to find the 2008R2 instance that you installed and type that into the "SQL Server Instance Name" box.

Comment: Hmm I already did. I can only find `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)`. Maybe I shoud deinstall Sql-Express and reinstall it completely? I'll give it a try...

Answer (score 1):

Might help to try to change the **compatibility level**, to make sure its backwards compatible.

Verify what level it is

```
USE VJ_DATABASE;
GO
SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'VJ_DATABASE';
GO
```

Then make it compatible with the older version

```
ALTER DATABASE VJ_DATABASE
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;   
GO
```

- 100 = Sql Server 2008
- 110 = Sql Server 2012
- 120 = Sql Server 2014

By default, Sql Server 2014 will change the db versions compatibility to only 2014, using the `@@ version` you should be able to tell, which version Sql Server is.

Then run the command above to change it the version you have.

*Additional step: Ensure you look at the accessibility of the DB is not reset, do this by right clicking on properties of the folder and the database. (make sure you have rights so you don't get an access denied)*

Answer (score 0):

I read this post but nothing helped me. Then I tried a few other options.

The way that I found that worked was to export the database and stored procedures from the original database. Then upload them into the second database(second computer).

Firstly export the DB content (data) - I used SQL server export data wizard. on the database you wish to export from right click then choose tasks, then export data. Follow the instructions and save in whichever format is best for you - I used excel for the data.

then to export the stored procedures rightclick the database name again. choose tasks and this time choose generate scripts. again follow the instructions of the wizard.

To import the data simply go to the second computer and right click the database you wish to import the data into. again tasks > import data. Follow the instructions to import all of the data from the database.

Finally to import the stored procedures, I opened up a new stored procedures command and dragged and dropped the script file that I had previously saved them in and dropped it into this window. The new stored procedure window filled with the entire list of my stored procedures. Finally change the name of the database name that will be used by the SP ( if this is different from the original DB name). (This is the first line USE [DBName]. then simply execute and the SP's will be fully restored.

This has helped me get my entire database up and running again very quickly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The **SQL Management Studio** is **different** than the **SQL Server Version** (or Database version).  Example:  At the current time, my work computer has **SQL Server 2012 Management Studio** but the **SQL Version is 9.0** – which is SQL Server 2005.  The **SQL Management studio** is **only an IDE** (Integrated Development Environment) and is **NOT** the same as the **SQL Server version**.

If when you try to **Attach** a Database, if you get an error similar to the following:

> “The database 'AdventureWorks2008' cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 612 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
>   Could not open new database 'AdventureWorks2008'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)”.

It means that the Database that you are trying to **Attach** was created with a **Newer** **SQL version** then what your computer has and you will **NOT** be able to use it.  See if they have that Database that was created with the **same or earlier version of SQL Server** that your computer uses.  In this case, I found the same Database that was created with SQL Server 2005 (Version 9).

A quick way to check what **SQL Server version the computer is running**, from the **Windows desktop**, go to Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc), click on the **Processess** tab, find and select the entry named “**sqlservr.exe**”, right click and choose **Properties**, click on the **Details** tab look at **Product Version** (Ex. 9….) or File **Version** (File version states the year and the version - Ex. 2005.9…).

Really this is the same error that i get, but until now i did not solve the problem!!

Answer (score -1):

This happens when you are trying to use the SQLServer Express to connect to the MDF file.  To remedy this issue, you need to go to `Services.msc` and turn on **SQL Server services**.  You need to set the log on properties and when the service is started, you will be able to connect to the MDF file without any issues.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Tools>Options>Data Connections`, provided you have installed SQL Server Express 2008r2, leave the SQL Server instance name blank.

Comment: There is no `instance name field` per se, so "leave it blank" would sound quite foreign to a novice.